# exim4 - Why is rate limiting outbound mail to a smarthost only working with acl_not_smtp?

Tags: email, smtp, exim, smarthost

In an effort to rate limit outgoing emails per recipient (all emails are sent by the same user), I've been doing some testing in a very simple environment:

```
                                         The Webs              

                                             ^                 
                                             |                 
+-------------------+   SMTP?         +--------+---------+       
|                   +---------------> | mail.example.com |       
| billyw.localhost  |                 |   (smarthost)    |       
|    (exim4)        |                 |                  |       
+-------------------+                 +------------------+
```

`billyw.localhost` is a Debian machine. Using `dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config`, I set it up to use `mail.example.com` as a smarthost.

Currently, I'm rate limiting by adding an ACL to `acl_not_smtp`:

```
acl_not_smtp = acl_check_not_smtp

acl_check_not_smtp:

  # Rate limit based on the recipient address
  discard
    ratelimit = 7 / 1m / per_mail / $recipients
    log_message = Rate limit exceeded for $recipients: $sender_rate/$sender_rate_period (max $sender_rate_limit)

  accept
```

I'm testing this with the following command on `billyw.localhost`:

```
for i in {1..10}; do
  mail -s testing billyw@mypersonalemail.com <<< ''
  mail -s testing billyw@myotherpersonalemail.com <<< ''
done
```

This configuration seems to work as intended; it allows 7 emails through to each recipient and discards the final 3 per recipient.

However, if I try to use this same configuration in an SMTP-related ACL, such as:

- `acl_smtp_connect`
- `acl_smtp_rcpt`
- `acl_smtp_mail`

Then the rate limiting entry of the ACL isn't hooked and all 10 messages are sent.

Why isn't the rate limiting being applied when it's put in an smtp-related ACL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `acl_not_smtp` is equivalent to `acl_data` for SMTP traffic.  Try rate limiting in that ACL.  SMTP connections give you more ACL options where you can place the message.  (Note: `discard` is a blackhole variant of `accept` so you won't see reject messages.)  Discarding is rather drastic, and I would use `defer` or `deny` for SMTP traffic.

Rate limiting is covered in [chapter 42](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-access_control_lists.html) section 38 of the [Exim Specification](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/).  You can test with modified configuration so you can rate limit harder while testing than you would once you implement.  Allow time for the test limits to clear before implementing.

Try adding the following to your `acl_smtp_rcpt`:

```
defer
  ratelimit = 7 / 1m / $recipients
  message = Rate limit exceeded for $recipients: \
            $sender_rate/$sender_rate_period (max $sender_rate_limit)
```

`/usr/bin/mail` runs the local `sendmail` program to deliver the mail rather than connecting over the network stack. In your case, exim4 is used as a drop-in replacement for sendmail. The mail will be treated as a non-smtp delivery. Rate limiting will need to be done using a non-smtp ACL.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I followed your recommendation, but `acl_smtp_rcpt` and `acl_smtp_data` aren't applying the rate limit to the outgoing messages. Which leads me to the question: Why do SMTP-related ACLs not apply to outbound emails sent to a smarthost via `/usr/bin/mail`? Is it actually sending batched SMTP instead of SMTP?

Comment: @billw `/usr/bin/mail` runs the local `sendmail` program to deliver the mail rather than connecting over the network stack.  In your case, `exim4` is used as a dropin replacement for `sendmail`.  The mail will be treated as a non-smtp deliviry.  Rate limiting will need to be done using a non-smtp ACL.

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot more sense. This whole time I thought I was limiting outbound traffic to the smarthost, but I was actually limiting inbound traffic from `/usr/bin/mail`! If you word your comment into the main text of your answer, then I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: @billyw I've added the sendmail process into the main answer.